# MySQL performance of LIKE (without wildcards) vs =

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I'm going to start of by saying that I know that you can't use indexes for LIKE queries if the value starts with a wildcard. This is NOT a question about that. I'm not using any wildcards.

In an application that accepts users to pass wildcard into queries, the value is passed to a query's LIKE clause. I've done some testing and have come to the conclusing that when searching for an exact address (so no wildcards) the query runs is slower than when I'm using an =. Take following 2 queries:

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'user@host.tld'`

vs

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'user@host.tld'`

Both queries will return the exact same records. When doing EXPLAIN on both, I can see that they are both using the index of the email field. The main difference is that the LIKE query is using a RANGE type, and the = query is using a REF type. Also, the RANGE query is examining some 1000 records where the = query is only examining 1 record (on 2 million records in the table).

The profiles of the query are the same, with the exception that the LIKE query uses significantly more time to process the "sending data" step, where it is actually examining the 1000 records. So basically, the query is slower because it is touching more data.

The thing I don't get, is to why it is doing that? Since the RANGE query is using the exact same index and exactly the same set of matches should be returned from the index, why is it examining more rows? This is probably a question about the internals of how a range query uses an index vs how the ref query does, but I can't seem to find any detailed information about it.

Comment: Are you sure the real value in your query doesn't contain any wildcards? Remember that `_` is a wildcard too…

Answer (score 3):

Q: why ... is [MySQL Optimizer] doing that?

A:

The short answer is that the optimizer is *not* converting the `LIKE` with no wildcards into an `=` operation.

---

MySQL optimizer only uses `ref` access for `=` and `<=>` comparisons.

MySQL optimizer can use `range` access for a lot more operations including `=`, `<=>`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `BETWEEN`, ...

A predicate like this:  `col LIKE 'foo'` is  being handled equivalent to

```
 col >= 'foo' AND col <= 'foo'
```

We look at that and say, that's the same as `col = 'foo'`, but the optimizer doesn't see it that way. The optimizer approach probably makes more sense if we use a wildcard. For example

```
 col LIKE `foo%bar`
```

MySQL could  use the `foo` portion for the "range" part of the scan, akin to this:

```
 col >= 'foo' AND col < 'fop'
```

MySQL optimizer can use an index range scan to satisfy the `>=` and `<` comparison.

(I use `fop` here as a simplistic representation of the lowest "higher weighted" string in the collating sequence.  We don't need to dive into charactersets and collating sequences, but just as a short justification of my use of 'fop', with latin1_swedish_ci collating sequence...

```
SELECT HEX(WEIGHT_STRING(_latin1'foo' AS CHAR(3)))  AS ws_foo
     , HEX(WEIGHT_STRING(_latin1'fop' AS CHAR(3)))  AS ws_fop
```

And for the rows that are found by the index range scan, the rest of the matching can be performed, akin to

```
 SUBSTR(col,4) LIKE '%bar'
```

---

I'm not saying that this is exactly how the MySQL optimizer is operating. (I haven't reviewed the source code.)

I'm suggesting that the MySQL optimizer is not treating `'col LIKE 'foo'` the same as `'col = 'foo'`, and the primary reason for that is the potential for wild card characters.

---

If we want `col = 'foo'` performance, we should write `col = 'foo'`.

We pay a price for a range scan when we opt for the flexibility of the `LIKE` comparison.

And we pay an even higher price (a full index scan, `index` operation in the EXPLAIN output), when we use a regular expression  `col REGEXP '^foo$'`.

---

**EDIT**

Even with the difference shown in the EXPLAIN plan, I wouldn't expect any measurable difference in performance of these two statements:

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'user@host.tld'
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM users WHERE email =    'user@host.tld'
```

For evaluating performance, I would run the statements four (or more) times in a row, capturing the execution time of each statement run, and throw out the result from the first run. Average the execution time of the runs except for the first. (We'd expect the execution times of the subsequent runs to be very close to each other.)

Note that other concurrent operations on the database could impact the performance of the statement we're measuring.

Answer (score 2):

The Optimizer...

- (effectively) turns a `LIKE` *without* any wild cards into `=`.
- turns `IN (one-item)` into `=`.
- turns `LIKE _with_ a _trailing_`%` (as the only wildcard) into a range test.
- cannot optimize `LIKE` with in most other situations with wildcards.
  These optimizations are useless without a relevant `INDEX`.

`sending data` is a useless metric.

Running a query the first time may have to load stuff from disk; the second time it will find stuff cached in RAM, hence be much faster.

`EXPLAIN's` "Rows" is an estimate; don't jump to any conclusions if the value varies by less than a factor of 2.

An `=` drills down the BTree to find the first matching row.  Then it scans forward to find any more matching rows.

Ditto for a "range" (`BETWEEN` or `LIKE 'foo%'` or ...) -- drill down to find the first (or last) item in the range, then scan forward (or backward).  Backward scanning happens *if* the Optimizer can use `ORDER BY .. DESC` at the same time.

(spencer7593's Answer goes into more detail.)